# High performance OpenCV matrix conversion from 16UC3 to 8UC3

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb

I have an OpenCV `CV_16UC3` matrix in which only the lower 8Bit per channel are occupied. I want to create a `CV_8UC3` from it. Currently I use this method:

```
cv::Mat mat8uc3_rgb(imgWidth, imgHeight, CV_8UC3);
mat16uc3_rgb.convertTo(mat8uc3_rgb, CV_8UC3);
```

This has the desired result, but I wonder if it can be faster or more performant somehow.

**Edit**:

The entire processing chain consists of only 4 sub-steps (computing time framewise determined by QueryPerformanceCounter measurement on video scene)

1. mount raw byte buffer in OpenCV-Mat: 
   `cv::Mat mat16uc1_bayer(imgHeight, RawImageWidth, CV_16UC1, (uint8*)payload);`
2. De-Mosaiking
   -> `cv::cvtColor(mat16uc1_bayer, mat16uc3_rgb, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR);`
   needs 0.008808[s]
3. pixel shift (only 12 of the 16 bits are occupied, but we only need 8 of them)
   -> uses openCV parallel access to the pixels using `mat16uc3_rgb.forEach<>`
   needs 0.004927[s]
4. conversion from CV_16UC3 to CV_8UC3
   `mat16uc3_rgb.convertTo(mat8uc3_rgb, CV_8UC3);`
   needs 0.006913[s]

I think I won't be able to do without the conversion of the raw buffer into CvMat or demosaiking. The pixel shift probably won't accelerate any further (here the parallelized forEach() is already used). I hoped that when converting from `CV_8UC3` to `CV_16UC3` an update of the matrix header info or similar would be possible, because the matrix data is already correct and doesn't have to be scaled anymore or similar.

Comment: Are you using opencv compiled with intel ipp or cuda ?

Comment: I think you can safely assume `cv:Mat::convertTo` is the fastest possible implementation. Are you sure your bottleneck is in the code you show?

Comment: @Ziri I can neither use IPP nor CUDA.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you for your advice. For more details on the processing chain see the edit on my question. Maybe one of the other steps could be done much more performant?

Comment: It's safe to assume that @JHBonarius comment is valid. Also in your two lines of code you've 2 bugs: 1) don't initialize the mat8uc3_rgb, specially if you use wrong size. The matrix is re-allocated by the convertTo function if it has the wrong size. The wrong size is because you swapped width and height, it should be rows (height) and columns (width). Also 2) convertTo doesn't care of the number of channels. So: `cv::Mat mat8uc3_rgb; mat16uc3_rgb.convertTo(mat8uc3_rgb, CV_8U);`

Comment: @Miki Thanks for your clues. At your first point, I agree with you unreservedly. On your second point, is this really a mistake? Even though cvtColor doesn't care about the number of channels internally, the code seems a bit more expressive to me. The intended result can also be read directly by someone, like me (even without deep understanding of what OpenCv internally checks and considers)

Comment: What if you write CV_8UC1? I would expect to change also the number of channels, which is note the case. BTW, I'm talking about convertTo, not cvtColor

Comment: "0.006913s" -> 6.913ms what? why are you complaining about time? At these durations the timer is not even that accurate. What kind of performance issues are your talking about?! Are you sure this is not just some micro-optimization?

Comment: @JHBonarius I am at a point where every microsecond counts, and of course you are right that this is micro-optimization. I was wondering, however, whether it might not be possible to avoid an unnecessary copy operation or whether I am missing something obvious. Based on your and Miki's remarks, I would now consider this question as settled (one of you would have to make an answer out of a comment, which I can then "accept"). BTW: With my underlying hardware, I'm assuming that if I use the QPC I'll achieve at least 0.8-1.0[ms] accuracy in timing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can safely assume that [`cv::Mat::convertTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) is the fastest possible implementation of that operation.
Seeing you are going from one colorspace to another, it will likely not be a zero-cost operation. Memory copy is required for rearranging.

If you are designing a very high-performance system, you should do in-depth analysis of your bottlenecks, and redesign you system to minimize them. Ask yourself: is this conversion really required at this point? Can I solve it by making a custom function that integrates multiple operations in one? Can I use CPU parallelism extensions, multithreading or GPU acceleration? Etc.